# Capture the Reverse Signal in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, telephony, pbx, agi

*I am new to and working on asterisk.*

How to Capture the Reverse Signal in Asterisk,
Currently I am receiving the disposition as **NA-No Answer Auto Dial** for all **unreached calls** where I should receive as follows

*No Answer, 
Busy,
Not Reachable, 
Switched Off*.

Currently using vicidial:   2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vicidial use app_AMD

```
Synopsis
Attempts to detect answering machines.

Description
AMD([|initialSilence][|greeting][|afterGreetingSilence][|totalAnalysisTime][|minimumWordLength][|betweenWordsSilence][|maximumNumberOfWords][|silenceThreshold])

This application attempts to detect answering machines at the beginning of outbound calls.
Simply call this application after the call has been answered (outbound only, of course).
When loaded, AMD reads amd.conf and uses the parameters specified as default values.
Those default values get overwritten when calling AMD with parameters.

    'initialSilence' is the maximum silence duration before the greeting. If exceeded then MACHINE.
    'greeting' is the maximum length of a greeting. If exceeded then MACHINE.
    'afterGreetingSilence' is the silence after detecting a greeting. If exceeded then HUMAN.
    'totalAnalysisTime' is the maximum time allowed for the algorithm to decide on a HUMAN or MACHINE.
    'minimumWordLength'is the minimum duration of Voice to considered as a word.
    'betweenWordsSilence' is the minimum duration of silence after a word to considere the audio what follows as a new word.
    'maximumNumberOfWords'is the maximum number of words in the greeting. If exceeded then MACHINE.
    'silenceThreshold' is the silence threshold.


This application sets the following channel variable upon completion:
AMDSTATUS - This is the status of the answering machine detection.
Possible values are:
MACHINE | HUMAN | NOTSURE | HANGUP
AMDCAUSE - Indicates the cause that led to the conclusion.
Possible values are:
TOOLONG-<%d total_time>
INITIALSILENCE-<%d silenceDuration>-<%d initialSilence>
HUMAN-<%d silenceDuration>-<%d afterGreetingSilence>
MAXWORDS-<%d wordsCount>-<%d maximumNumberOfWords>
LONGGREETING-<%d voiceDuration>-<%d greeting>
```

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+AMD

Comment: How to rectify this error. **astxs** is not found in asterisk-1.4.36 version. `chmod: cannot access /usr/src/asterisk/asterisk-1.4.36/contrib/scripts/astxs': No such file or directory`

Comment: SO is not debuging site.

Comment: Any Alternative which can fix it.